# For AWS, how do you set tags to a resource with the ruby aws-sdk?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ruby

I'm pretty new to using Amazon's ruby-sdk (gem install aws-sdk), and am stuck trying to simply  create a tag for a snapshotted resource. Here's what I'm doing:

```
ec2.tags.create(:resource_id => "snap-7d3aa701", :key => "My Test Tag", :value => "My test value")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

Note, ec2 = AWS::EC2.new (after I set my credentials).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I haven't been able to find a single example online of using the ruby aws-sdk for tagging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to tag an EC2 resource is it use the #tags method:

```
ec2.snapshots["snapshot-id"].tags["tag"] = "value"
```

If you want a handle to the tag object created, you can still use the TagCollection#create method.  It expects the first param to be a resource:

```
tag = ec2.tags.create(ec2.snapshots['snapshot-id'], 'tag') # no tag value

tag = ec2.tags.create(ec2.snapshots['snapshot-id'], 'tag', 'value')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely just caused by a typo, the first parameter name should be `resource` rather than `resource_id` - see the [API reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html) of the [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/) for the [create(resource, key, options = {})](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/TagCollection.html#create-instance_method) instance method, which provides two short examples as well:

> Creates a new Tag and assigns it to an EC2 resource.
>
> **Examples**:
>
> **tagging with names (keys) only**
> `ec2.tags.create(instance, 'webserver')`
>
> **tagging with names (keys) and values**
> `ec2.tags.create(instance, 'stage', 'production')`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - resource (Object) — The item to tag. This should be a taggable EC2 resource, like an instance,
>   security group, etc.
> - key (String) — The tag key (or name).
> - options (Hash) (defaults to: {}) optins (Hash) — a customizable set of options
>
> **Returns**:
>
> - ([Tag](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Tag.html))