# Create a name to a EC2 instance by using AWS API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the following code in my app.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'rubygems'

AWS.config({
 :access_key_id => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 :secret_access_key => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
})
ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(:ec2_endpoint => 'ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com')
@@i = ec2.instances.create(:image_id => 'ami-aabXXXXX', :instance_type => 't1.micro', :security_groups=> ['Drum-Factory'], :key_name => 'some-key' )
sleep 1 while @@i.status == :pending
......
```

How can i name my instance while creating it, so that it will appear in the Name column of my AWS Management Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name column is actually a tag added to the instance
So you need to set the value of "Name" tag

My guess is something like this

```
@@i.tags["Name"] = "value"
```

or

```
tag = ec2.tags.create(@@i, "Name","Value")
```

check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/TagCollection.html#create-instance_method

also this SO answer might be of help
[For AWS, how do you set tags to a resource with the ruby aws-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584123/for-aws-how-do-you-set-tags-to-a-resource-with-the-ruby-aws-sdk)